# String with the smallest sum of ASCII values

Tags: code-golf, string, array

### Description

In this challenge, you need to write a function that takes in a list of strings and returns the smallest string based on their ASCII value. You should assume that the input list contains only lowercase alphabetical strings.

### Test Cases

```
["a", "b", "c"] => "a"
["hello", "world", "code"] => "code"
["aaa", "aa", ""] => ""
["cat", "bat", "rat"] => "bat"
["zab", "xyz", "abcd"] => "zab"
```

Write the function in as few bytes as possible. The code itself can be a function, process or anything provided that it gives the desired output. Use of other ASCII characters like big or small letters, with space function must be supported.

Comment: "Smallest string based on ASCII value" as in the string with the smallest sum of ASCII values?

Comment: @Seggan precisely correct, the individual ASCII values are added

Comment: I suggest you clarify that in the post

Comment: Suggested test case: `["zab", "xyz", "abcd"] => "zab"`

Comment: I suggest you remove the requirement of supporting extended ASCII. With standard ASCII the logic of the algorithm is probably the same, and it allows more languages to participate

Comment: @LuisMendo you can directly edit without asking i guess 

Comment: What should the function return if there are two strings with the same sum, like `["bbt", "cat", "rat"]`?

Comment: @AitzazImtiaz Your challenge, your choice 

Comment: @ErikF it will go random then, nice test case

Comment: You have an example with an empty string. This doesn't have an ASCII value. Unless you mean the `NUL` character which has value of `0`?

Comment: it means lowest ascii value is non-existent so the output is non-existent and cannot output NUL or 0 both,

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ΣÇO}н
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3OLD7f61F/b@/x@tlJGak5OvpKOgVJ5flJMCYiTnp6QqxQIA)

##### Explanation

```python
ΣÇO}н # Implicit input
Σ  }  # Sort by:
 Ç    #  ASCII values
  O   #  Sum
    н # First item
      # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 3):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), <s>18</s> 16 bytes

-2 from Dominic van Essen for replacing `'0'` with `@`.

```
{⊑˜⊑⍒(+´@⊸-)¨}
```

[Try it online!](https://bqnpad.mechanize.systems/s?bqn=eyJkb2MiOiIjIFtcImFcIiwgXCJiXCIsIFwiY1wiXSA9PiBcImFcIlxuIyBbXCJoZWxsb1wiLCBcIndvcmxkXCIsIFwiY29kZVwiXSA9PiBcImNvZGVcIlxuIyBbXCJhYWFcIiwgXCJhYVwiLCBcIlwiXSA9PiBcIlwiXG4jIFtcImNhdFwiLCBcImJhdFwiLCBcInJhdFwiXSA9PiBcImJhdFwiXG5pbiDihpAg4p%2BoXCJoZWxsb1wiLCBcIndvcmxkXCIsIFwiY29kZVwi4p%2BpXG578J2VqeKKkcuc4oqR4o2SKCvCtCcwJ%2BKKuC0pwqjwnZWpfWluIiwicHJldlNlc3Npb25zIjpbXSwiY3VycmVudFNlc3Npb24iOnsiY2VsbHMiOltdLCJjcmVhdGVkQXQiOjE2NzQ5Mzc2OTI1NzZ9LCJjdXJyZW50Q2VsbCI6eyJmcm9tIjowLCJ0byI6MTc3LCJyZXN1bHQiOm51bGx9fQ%3D%3D)

#### Explanation

```
{⊑˜⊑⍒(+´@⊸-)¨}  
{              ¨} 1. For each string in the (monadic) input 
{     (  @⊸-)  } 2a. convert the string to (negative) its unicode representation...
{     (+´     )  } 2b. and perform a sum reduction.
{    ⍒(       )  } 3. return descending-sorted indices.
{   ⊑            } 4. take the first.
{⊑˜             } 5. take this index into the input  where ˜ "flips" the next function.
```

Comment: Save 2 bytes by changing ```'0'``` to ```@```...

Comment: Cheers, I didn't know about `@` :s

Answer (score 3):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 22 bytes

```factor
[ [ sum ] infimum-by ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY3NCsIwEITvfYoxd30ARa/ixYt4Kj2kaYqB/JmmaFr67LEbkB52YOebne25iC7k5@N2vx4xyPcorZADfJAxJh@UjThVczWDcQbWriMYFuxwvpBF4CW1div4uKA7CrhObpmylXtODUU2WojgkbqLBtI/JYsCE6fH3zRRQSu6LUGkWnKNGsNo0EDZXpnR7NuEJhvuccg/)

Answer (score 3):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 57 bytes

```java
l->l.stream().min((a,b)->a.chars().sum()-b.chars().sum())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVC9TsMwEJ7JU1iZbJT4BVIyMoEYOiKGi/NTF8e27EshrfrswXFSCQQD8XCn@07fz/kIJ8iP9fske2sckmOY@YBS8XbQAqXR/L5Ifi2fpMc/4Bc7M0AViR0qJQURCrwnzyA1uSQkPI@AAX9cxXez0G6PTuquzMiNf0NK0j5MKi8V9@ga6CnjvdSUQlaxvAQuDuB8AP0QVnn1c2ZTES3XKKvzycia9CEQXTxe3wi4zrNLcrcfPTY9NwNyG1aoNG05WKtGOsfkpqUppBlJq7mIlDHeNRiMiv9xD41SZqZ@GKfqqGHqZrMMQAyx1M1sARhPWJoLbavCGeL9n@M5xqhE/V1i/vFrcp2@AA)

Takes input as a `List<String>` and returns an `Optional<String>`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), <s>5</s> 4 bytes

```
‡C∑P
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLigKFD4oiRUCIsIiIsIltcImhlbGxvXCIsXCJ3b3JsZFwiLFwiY29kZVwiXSJd)

*-1 thanks to @mathcat*

##### Explanation

```python
‡C∑P  # Implicit input
‡  P  # Minimum by:
 C    #  ASCII values
  ∑   #  Sum
      # Implicit output
```

Old:

```python
C∑)ṡh # Implicit input
  )ṡ  # Sort by:
C     #  ASCII values
 ∑    #  Sum
    h # First item
      # Implicit output
```

Comment: [4 bytes](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLigKFD4bmgUCIsIiIsIltcInp6elwiLCBcImN6elwiLCBcImRhYVwiXSJd)

Comment: @mathcat thanks, updated

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 92 bytes

```c
f(s,t,u,i,c)char**s,*t,*u;{for(i=~0,u=0;t=*s;c<i+0U?u=*s,i=c:0,s++)for(c=0;*t;c+=*t++);s=u;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZBNbsMgEIX3OcXIUhWMpxLrUtpTdOV6QcZxg@TYlYH@JHKv7g64kSq12Txg5mMePLp9IVqWTngMGNEhlXSwk5QeZUAZ9bkbJ@HMl8JolA5Gek33rlJPj5H36AzdKfRVVSaOGJFBU2Vk4JL2Jup5cUOAo3WDeBtdW8J5A5A8gE3qxqQjgMiudcNtKGyBUOySEIuCGf8yh33fjwl5H6e@zezY7q/i1uahq16lyIZsvS5TXv4nTza/7@PzlMfuqP2NKtYZ@YOcIWvUGy6kgILxGjghSPHA@vXXiQPqRFFDUepcSSSnyxhfhZjQC7S98VtgKxl/2EujAfMAqfs8cLsTMpSZmDfz8g0)

Ungolfed:

```c
f(s,t,u,i,c)char**s,*t,*u;{
  for(i=~0, // initialize minimum string sum to largest possible
      u=0; // initialize smallest string (in case of empty list)
      t=*s; // scan list
      c<i+0U?u=*s,i=c:0, // reset minimum string sum and pointer if smaller
      s++)
    for(c=0;*t;c+=*t++); // get string sum
  s=u; // return smallest string
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Swift, <s>64</s>  69 bytes

<sup>*Now with fewer compiler crashes!*</sup>

```
{$0.map{($0.reduce(0){$0+Int($1.asciiValue!)},$0)}.min{$0.0<$1.0}!.1}
```

[SwiftFiddle link](https://swiftfiddle.com/nwsbjcbcmfbfraijjpnba3ppp4)

Comment: The original version only worked for short strings; after more than a couple characters, it would overflow the limit for `UInt8`. However, when you hardcode the input, constant-folding causes this overflow to happen at compile-time, an the compiler crashes.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 44 bytes

```python
lambda l:min(l,key=lambda x:sum(map(ord,x)))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3dXISc5NSEhVyrHIz8zRydLJTK22hQhVWxaW5GrmJBRr5RSk6FZqamlA9KgVFmXklGmka0UoZqTk5-Uo6Ckrl-UU5KSBGcn5KqlIsTO2CBRAaAA)

##### Commented

```python
lambda l:                                     # Anonymous function taking l, a list of strings
         min(l,                            )  # Return the minimum of l...
               key=                           # ...using the following function:
                   lambda x:                  #  Function taking x, a string
                            sum(          )   #  Sum the following:
                                map(ord,x)    #  Convert all characters to ASCII values
```

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 59 bytes

```javascript
a=>a.sort(g=(x,y)=>x>=x&&~~eval(Buffer(x).join`+`)-g(y))[0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Zc7NCoMwDAfw@55CepCW@bEXqIe9hghmtXVKMaM6Vy@@emfrYUNz@IcQfiQ9zDAK072mdMBGOsUd8AKyEc1EW05tsjBe2ILbOF5XOYOm97dS0lDLsh67ob7WLG3pwlh5q5zAYUQtM40tVbQkQJKIPHwIUjEW/VeeR9v@ciRPqTV68UGjm0C3x3btSZhOCiCc2vNwyquzEDCF5/ZmtvZTXviF@wI)

#### Commented

```javascript
a =>            // a[] = input array
a.sort(g =      // g is a recursive callback function
  (x, y) =>     // for each pair (x, y) to be tested:
    x >= x &&   //   stop if x is undefined
    ~~eval(     //   otherwise, evaluate as JS code:
      Buffer(x) //     the ASCII codes of x
      .join`+`  //     joined with '+'
    )           //   end of eval()
    - g(y)      //   subtract the result of a recursive call with x = y
)               // end of sort()
[0]             // keep the first entry
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-g`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 4 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Takes input as an array of character arrays.

```
ñÈxc
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LWc&header=bXE&code=8ch4Yw&input=WwoiemFiIgoieHl6IgoiYWJjZCIKXS1Q)

```
ñÈxc     :Implicit input of 2D array
ñ        :Sort by
 È       :Function
  x      :  Sum of
   c     :    Codepoints
         :Implicit output of first element
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/) +old utils, 47 <s>55</s> <s>103</s> bytes

Using the filesystem and the old System V [`sum`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sum-invocation.html)* command:

```sh
for i;echo $i>$[++n];set `sum -s *|sort -n`;<$3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZUxLCsIwFNz3FEPJQi1duYx4ERH68jOVmkCSUo169pisHRgG5pejLWa3f3erizrBFeMDZq6l9WDzmV2GwV15i6a4PjBGHD7Rh4TRTfzEjuXbGeR/IOr7bG5WgYSsFYJAU6uXxWPzYVGQXulqSUoQlYFS@yKB5yu3mWo7okr0ffkB)
  <s><sub>[55 bytes](https://tio.run/##ZUxLCsIwFNz3FEPpQi1ZiMuIF5FCX36mUhNIUtRazx6TtQPDwPzWaLPZ7T/N4qJOcNn4gIlraT266dJd@94NvEZjXB5gEYct@pDA3GY1KbDjyM/dKX8bg/UfiPo@mZtVICFLhSBQ1ep59nj6MCtIr3SxJCWIwkCpfpHA673Wmao7okK0bf4B)</sub></s>

<sub>* On MacOS, `cksum -o2` is equivalent to GNU `sum -s`. According to Wikipedia, the [BSD checksum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSD_checksum) algorithm is "useless from a security perspective"</sub>

---

##### 103 bytes, using arrays and builtins only:

```sh
for x;{w=;for a (${(s::)${x:?}})((w+=#a));k+=($w)}
for i ({1..$#})((k[i]==$(printf ${(n)k})))&&<<<$@[i]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVBNa4NAEL3nVzyihF0SAqU3o6SH9tpD2lvpYdRRNxpX3E01ir/d7vbUgcd8vPeGYSZTrYWQ8@beGrYgKFxRY1wL3WM8zUNy8hVBhLMwUSTDeYzOyyKFGPZJQFKe6n0iwkEuGy9UEPPT8RgGXlF/qe8kCUXXq9YWcBtaWS9Syt0ujuPwxdGrs8HwVRVllYPSzLWEFD5X3DQag@6bHJnO2Y0yskgderKumyjF@Ji8Lfc@Igdst/gXwbu2fICtGM99jh9q7gxlQC341tkHjHXXlTAarbaVLx37dzHnB/CYcef/cmNjqGToFh@fr2@Xy/oL)

<sub>Explanation of code is in earlier revisions of this answer</sub>

Answer (score 1):

## Excel, 78 bytes

```
=LET(x,A1#,y,ROW(A:A),@SORTBY(x,MMULT(TOROW(y^0),IFERROR(CODE(MID(x,y,1)),))))
```

where `A1#` is a *horizontal* spilled range containing the strings.

Comment: In theory I thought `=@SORTBY(A1#,MAP(A1#,LAMBDA(x,SUM(IFERROR(CODE(MID(x,ROW(A:A),1)),)+1))))` for 73 bytes would work. Using the implicit intersection operator should return the top-left cell. However, it's either bugged or not working as I expected.

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), <sup><s>9</s></sup> 5 bytes

*And pure ASCII!*

```
{|+}e
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%7B%7C%2B%7De&i=%5B%22a%22,+%22b%22,+%22c%22%5D%0A%5B%22hello%22,+%22world%22,+%22code%22%5D+%0A%5B%22aaa%22,+%22aa%22,+%22%22%5D%0A%5B%22cat%22,+%22bat%22,+%22rat%22%5D%0A%5B%22zab%22,+%22xyz%22,+%22abcd%22%5D&m=2) (with test cases)

## Explanation

```
{  }e # minimum by
 |+   # sum
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage/wiki/Code-page)

```
OS$ÞḢ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/98/WOXwvIc7Fv3//z9aKQMolq@ko6BUnl@UkwJiJOenpCrFAgA)

##### Explanation

```python
OS$ÞḢ  # Main link
  $    # Last two links as a monad:
O      #  Ordinals
 S     #  Sum
   Þ   # Sort the input by this monad
    Ḣ  # First item (minimum)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 12 bytes

```
@Y{$+A*a}SKg
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgwYKlpSVpuhZrHCKrVbQdtRJrg73TIUJQma3RSsmJJUo6CkpJEKoISMVCJQE)

##### Explanation

```lisp
@Y{$+A*a}SKg  ; Input on command line
           g  ; Input list
  {     }SK   ; Sorted by:
   $+         ;  Sum of
     A*       ;  ASCII values of
       a      ;  The string
@Y            ; First item (minimum)
              ; Implicit output
```

Comment: Just noticing this answer a year later... you can save two bytes on the function by using a lambda expression `$+A*_`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Raku](https://raku.org/), 17 bytes

```
*.min(*.ords.sum)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYpNCsMgGAWv8pBQ2lBcdlPjVcLnHy1obTQhNSFntwbeLGZ4X5v8o4aCi8NQex7en2vPYzKZ5yXc6hOZClg3YpDYHbrxYHAxQRAUtLxDvKz3EWtM3kBHY1ubplUQEdoYOz@aZqhGovnUjRR@ZQMpbWT9Aw)

`*.ords.sum` is an anonymous function that calculates the sum of the ordinal values of its string argument.  That function is passed as the argument to `*.min`, which returns the element of the input list with the smallest value computed by the first function.

Comment: Your explanation seems to break off at a

Comment: Huh!  Fixed.  Dunno how that happened.

Answer (score 1):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 9 bytes

```
{)**++}<m
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/V@tpGBrp2RtrRtblPi/WlNLS1u71ib3f214zv9opUQlHQWlJBCRrBQLVKcAFOGKVspIzcnJB4mW5xflpICl81NSoSrATKCixESwbggJlQOJJyeWgE2FUEVACiIHEgBKVyWC7auorALrTkpOgcqDJAA)

```
{
 )** # Map to ord
 ++  # sum
}<m  # Minimum by
```

Answer (score 1):

## [janet](https://janet-lang.org), 51 bytes

```scheme
(fn[l](((sort-by first(map(fn[x][(sum x)x])l))0)1))
```

in janet, you can save bytes by not using spaces between brackets, which i personally think is very ugly for a lisp-like language, so here's an de-uglified version and an example

```scheme
(fn [l] (((sort-by first (map (fn [x] [(sum x) x]) l)) 0) 1))
```

```scheme
$ janet
Janet 1.29.1-20230709 openbsd/x64/clang - '(doc)' for help
repl:1:> (def F (fn[l](((sort-by first(map(fn[x][(sum x)x])l))0)1)))
<function 0x028B13B5F580>
repl:2:> (F ["zab" "xyz" "abcd"])
"zab"
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 42 bytes

```arturo
$=>[minimum&=>[∑to[:integer]to[:char]&]]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?xKuDUd)

Answer (score 0):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 74 bytes

```
.
$&$&96$*~
0T1`l`L`\w\w
{`[J-Z]
9$&
}T`_L`dL
\d
$*~
+`(\w)~
~$1
O`
1G`
~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P9fj0tFTUXN0kxFq47LIMQwISfBJyGmPKacqzoh2ks3KpbLUkWNqzYkId4nIcWHKyaFC6RQO0EjplyzjqtOxZDLP4HL0D2Bq47r///EpOQUrorKKq6qxCQA) Only accepts strings of lowercase letters. Explanation:

```
.
$&$&96$*~
```

Duplicate each letter and suffix 96 `~`s to each pair.

```
0T1`l`L`\w\w
```

Uppercase alternate letters.

```
{`[J-Z]
9$&
}T`_L`dL
```

Map uppercase letters into digits that sum to their index i.e. `A=1` to `Z=998`.

```
\d
$*~
```

Expand the digits into that many `~`s.

```
+`(\w)~
~$1
```

Move all of the `~`s to the beginning of the string.

```
O`
```

Sort the strings into order. Since `~` sorts after `z`, this means that the string with the fewest `~`s will sort first.

```
1G`
```

Keep only the first string.

```
~
```

Delete the `~`s.

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 15 bytes

```
ＵＭθ⟦↨Ｅι℅λ¹ι⟧⊟⌊θ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fcg9C4MwEIDhvb8iZLqDdOjsprPoHjKcieBBPjS2Yv3zVzu8PPD6haovFEV6WruSEuUAm1G2pX2G@wEbNdTAmSJERKNed@yweYyV8xvGskLPmdMnwYaIjYi1miYftFH6/F5/Lpq0c/I84g8) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
ＵＭθ⟦↨Ｅι℅λ¹ι⟧
```

Calculate the sum of ASCII values for each string.

```
⊟⌊θ
```

Output the string with the smallest sum.

Answer (score 0):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 55 bytes

```powershell
($args|Sort-Object{"$($_|% t*y|%{'+',+$_[0]})"|iex})[0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RU/JboMwED3jrxhZTsENSP2BSEhVe23V9BZFyJjJJlqntlEW4NupbUhyme1tmqM6oTY7rOtMKo0D2yzaIWFCb023VNpmH@UBpW0pS1jRzcA@X7pZG8/jdM6K1cu657Tb47nnbh56QvKERGme5AkVNAVa@iIpd1VQfoN8nPLISem6ChRVYWCNw91DBJexBvyBSWFDwti0a3xa75SrCPnnyzW4lLIKHH/mhEMH70q/CbmbnoSWRMyisSkwPB/dBStYACvcWaNpauu2J7aB3JNItPpcvjbGqp9RvobcGUTLRko0xgsnUYZ/D0PH@HZqD3sXyA5q/wtxCrFDvm4pk5REPenJ8A8)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 6 bytes

```
.msCMb
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/Xy@32Nk36f//aKWqxCQlHQWlisoqEJWYlJyiFAsA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 2 bytes

```
◄Σ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6f@6ip8f@j6S3nFv///z86WilRSUcpCYiTlWJ1opUyUnNy8oG88vyinBSQaH5KKlgiMRGkEEyA@cmJJSCNYLIISILEqhJBBlVUVoFUJiWnKMXGAgA)

```
◄     # minlon: Element that minimizes function result
 Σ    # chrsum: Sum of code points
```

Answer (score 0):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), <s>15</s> 14 bytes

```
⊑∘⍋∘(+´¨-⟜@)⊑⊢
```

[Try it at BQN REPL](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=U21hbGxlc3Rfc3VtIOKGkCDiipHiiJjijYviiJgoK8K0wqgt4p+cQCniipHiiqIKU21hbGxlc3Rfc3Vtwqgg4p+o4p+oImhlbGxvIiwgIndvcmxkIiwgImNvZGUi4p+pLOKfqCJjYXQiLCAiYmF0IiwgInJhdCLin6ks4p+oInphYiIsICJ4eXoiLCAiYWJjZCLin6nin6k=)

```
⊑∘⍋∘(+´¨-⟜@)⊑⊢
    (  ¨    )       # for each element of input
        -⟜@         #   subtract the null character from each letter
                    #   (thereby getting codepoint values)
     +´             #   and sum by fold-addition
⊑∘                  # now get the first element of 
  ⍋∘                # the indices of sorted elements
             ⊑      # and use this to select from
              ⊢     # the elements of the input
```